# LocalDate.parse (Not Working)

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdate

Please! I would like to understand why this simple LocalDate parsing isn't working!

My DateFormatter works (in both ways), but when I'm trying to parse into a new LocalDate variable (using the same Formatter), it doesn't work and I get the following exception.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd-yyyy"); 
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String dateFormatted = date.format(dateTimeFormatter); 

System.out.println("Data formatted > " + dateFormatted); 
String dateFormatted1 = dateTimeFormatter.format(date); 
System.out.println("Data formatted  2> " + dateFormatted1); 

LocalDate dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(dateTimeFormatter.format(date));
System.out.println("Data parsed > " + dateParsed); 

LocalDate dateParsed2 = LocalDate.parse(dateFormatted, dateTimeFormatter); 
System.out.println("Data parsed 2 > " + dateParsed2);
```

---

/////////////////////// Exception //////////////////////////////

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'dez-11-2017' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:385)
    at hypercaos.AddController.initialize(AddController.java:74)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)*
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the function know which one is the formatter:

```
LocalDate dateParsed = LocalDate.parse(dateTimeFormatter.format(date), dateTimeFormatter);
```

When you parse without the Formatter, LocalDate will understand it as `yyyy-MM-dd`, and your String is `MMM-dd-yyyy`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. 
Actually, I made a mistake.

I thought that doing that, I could capture the variable dateParsed in MMM-dd-yyyy format already (to show it later without doing LocalDate -> String format conversion).
But what it does is just turn to yyyy-MM-dd again. 

Thank you!

Ps.: Sorry about the silly question!! :-)